# How to extract data from xeditable select2 field in django..?

Tags: javascript, python, django, x-editable, jquery-select2

I am struggling to make a working xditable select2 field.

The code is as below:

```
 <a href="#" data-pk="" class="uassignment"  id="uassignment" name="uassignment" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var source =  [
              {id: 'A', text: 'A'},
              {id: 'B', text: 'B'}

           ];


$('#uassignment').editable({  //to keep track of selected values in multi select
 name: 'assignment',
   inputclass: 'some_class',
   showSearchBox: false,
    type: 'select2',
    url: '/myurl/assignmentupdate/',
    source : source ,
    params: function(params) {
    params.pk = $("#updateid").val();
    return params;
},
 title: 'Assignment',

    select2: {
        multiple : true,
         emptytext: 'None',
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1
    }
});
```

This code is working fine at the browser end. However when I tried to retrieve the selected values at server it is returning empty list.
(In Django View)

```
assignment_list = request.POST.getlist('value')
print(assignment_list)  //This statement returns empty list
assignment_list = ','.join(assignment_list)
temp.assignment = assignment_list
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you using `getlist` instead of `get`?

Comment: @ilse2005  Because the value parameter is passed as list (e..g. value=A,B,C). If I try get it throws an error.

Comment: What version of Select2 and what version of x-editable?

Comment: @ilse2005 Select2 Version: 3.5.2 and bootstrap editable Version:  v1.5.1